# How to enqueue glider.js?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I've built a static site in html, css and js that I've converted into a wordpress theme. I've used glider.js for an image slider. The slider works perfect locally as a static html/css/js site.

Converting the site to a wordpress template, I have two js files and have enqueued both my app.js file and glider.min.js in my functions.php file.

```
// Add javascript start
function load_js() {
    wp_register_script('javascript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/app.js', array(), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('javascript');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js');

//glide js

function load_glide() {
    wp_register_script('load_glide', get_template_directory_uri() . '/glide.min.js', array(), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('load_glide');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_glide');

// Add javascript end
```

When I view the wordpress site live glider.js doesn't work. I get the console error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Glide is not defined". The js file glider.min.js is in the right place when I check the sourcecode for the page in dev tools. Why am I getting "Glide is not defined" when glider.min.js has been enqueued? the "Glide" object is in app.js but needs glide.min.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is WordPress related and how it handles loading scripts.

Your `app.js` file depends on `glide.min.js`, so you have to explicitly tell that when registering scripts into the WordPress with `wp_register_script` function. It accepts an array of dependent scripts ids as a third parameter.

```
// Add javascript start
function load_js() {
    wp_register_script('javascript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/app.js', array('load_glide'), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('javascript');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js');

//glide js

function load_glide() {
    wp_register_script('load_glide', get_template_directory_uri() . '/glide.min.js', array(), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('load_glide');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_glide');

// Add javascript end
```

Note that I added the `load_glide` id when registering `app.js` file.